# Opening a composable screen from a non-composable callback

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to open the WebView from my callback. But I am getting the following error

`@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

This code snippet is the issue

```
onNewsLinkedClicked = { newsLink ->
                            WebViewScreen(webLink = newsLink)
                        }
```

I did try and declare my lambda in the NewsScreen function like this.

`onNewsLinkedClicked: @Composable (newsLink: String) -> Unit`

That solved the issue below. But then I got another issue, as I launch the callback from a Button onClick event which started to give me an error.

Is there any way of doing this for my code below?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val newsViewModel: NewsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            val newsHeadLines = newsViewModel.newsPager.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

            BeerPagingTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                val scrollBehavior = enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    NewsScreen(
                        newsPagingData = newsHeadLines,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .nestedScroll(connection = scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
                        topAppBarScrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
                        onNewsLinkedClicked = { newsLink ->
                            WebViewScreen(webLink = newsLink)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun WebViewScreen(webLink: String) {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->

            WebView(context).apply {
                this.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

                loadUrl(webLink)
            } },
        update = { webView ->
            webView.loadUrl(webLink)
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
}
```

Comment: You probably want to look at a navigation solution, whether you use the official Navigation for Compose or Appyx or compose-destinations or Voyager or any of the couple of dozen other third-party navigation libraries. Alternatively, your button should mutate some state that causes you to show `WebViewScreen()` instead of `NewsScreen()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not sure what you mean by this `Alternatively, your button should mutate some state that causes you to show WebViewScreen() instead of NewsScreen()` Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scalability, I recommend using one of the many navigation solutions available for Compose UI. That could be Navigation for Compose, if you want a purely official solution. If you want a wrapper over that, consider [compose-destinations](https://github.com/raamcosta/compose-destinations). If you want something fully independent, there are [Appyx](https://bumble-tech.github.io/appyx) and [Voyager](https://voyager.adriel.cafe/) and many others.

Tactically, you could do something like:

```kotlin
            BeerPagingTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                val scrollBehavior = enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
                var newsLink by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    if (newsLink == null) {
                        NewsScreen(
                            newsPagingData = newsHeadLines,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .nestedScroll(connection = scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
                            topAppBarScrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
                            onNewsLinkedClicked = { newsLink = it }
                        )
                    } else {
                        WebViewScreen(webLink = newsLink)
                    }
                }
            }
```

(note: I'm doing this from memory, so there may need to be some adjustments)

Compose is a declarative reactive framework. You *declare* "this is what I want the UI to be, based upon the current state". In this case, the current state is `newsLink`. You *react* to changes in that state. So, your `onClick` lambda updates the state (`newsLink = it`), causing Compose to re-run all of `setContent()` and update the UI based upon a fresh declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [navigation solution](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation).
Alternatively, your button should mutate some state that causes you to show `WebViewScreen()` instead of `NewsScreen()` as below:

```
var clickedLink by rememberSavable { mutableStateOf("") }// state for saving clicked link
if (clickedLink.isEmpty) {
          NewsScreen(
                        newsPagingData = newsHeadLines,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .nestedScroll(connection = scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
                        topAppBarScrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
                        onNewsLinkedClicked = { newsLink ->
                            clickedLink = newsLink // changing clicked link address
                        }
                    )
} else {
    WebViewScreen(webLink = clickedLink)
}
```